# limiting access to a class's interface in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

I have situation where I have to restrict the access to a class. to further elaborate, I have two classes, say `A` and `B` that depend on class `C`, but `A` doesn't need to use the complete interface of `C`, the same goes to `B`. What I did was, make `C` implement two different interfaces, one interface `A` can access, the other for `B` to refer to. What I am doing here, is it correct? or should I just document this? or else is there a better approach?

To give more context, I am trying to implement an system which allows an interface for plug-ins. And I don't want someone accessing parts of a class I don't want them to.

Comment: Does it do what you want it to do? Do your tests pass? Then it's correct. Note that this will never prevent anyone to call a method that is not in the interface if he/she really wants to. It will only prevent hiM:er from doing it by mistake.

Comment: that was my problem, it does work, (at least for now) but is it okey to have the interface of a class i don't want a third party to use accessible in a situation like this?

Comment: divide C's contract into multiple interfaces and expose only relevant interface in other parts of the code. I don't see any problem in this approach.

Comment: You're confusing object design with security. If you absolutely don't want someone to call a method of some of your class, then he shouldn't have access to the class **at all**. And I don't mean making it private or anything. As soon as you make a plugin system, you accept foreign code to do basically whatever it wants to. You can design things to prevent the plugin author to shoot himself in the foot by accident, but that's all. If the plugin author has access to the code and is decided to use dirty tricks (reflection, etc.) to do what he wants, then he'll do it.

Comment: A concrete example: String is immutable. You can't change the contents of a String object, because no method of the String class allows that. It was a design decision, and everybody relies on it. But using reflection, it's very easy to actually change a String contents and break that design contract. Immutability is a design decision used to prevent bugs. It's not a security measure to prevent a malicious (or stupid) developer to do what he wants to.

Comment: so i am asking the wrong question. then how do I allow the author do something legal within the system while imposing security? i was under the assumption that should be taken into account when designing the system.

Comment: If security is such a concern, nobody should have access to your code. It should execute on your own machines.

Comment: so if i am designing a plug in system, what is the ideal way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your design. But the reason for your design should be a clear design, and not security. Given that `A` and `B` have access to the class `C` (for example, because `C` is public) they can access the entire object in its entirety: they can just cast the object they receive to `C` and then access it:

```
public interface IA {
    void f();
}
public interface IB {
    void g();
}
public class C implements IA, IB { 
    public void f() { ... }
    public void g() { ... }        
}
public class A {
    public void doSomething(IA anIA) {
        C aC = (C) anIA;
        aC.g(); // legal!
    }
}
```

This is often not a problem, because you are the programmer of `A`, `B`, and `C`. You trust yourself, so you need a clear design, but you do not need security.

Even if `C` is not public and `A` and `B` cannot access the class directly, they still can using reflection.

So if you cannot trust `A` and `B`, because they are programmed by an external party (e.g. they are plugins), you cannot use this design. You have to send objects which really only implement the interface which you want the plugin to access:

```
public class C { 
    public void f() { ... }
    public void g() { ... } 

    public IA getAsIO() {
        return new IA() {
            public void f() {
                C.this.f();
            }
        };
    }

    public IB getAsIB() { 
        // similar
    }
}
public class A {
    public void doSomething(IA anIA) {
        C aC = (C) anIA; // illegal
        aC.g();
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually does answer my question above. and i also realise that I was looking in the wrong places to solve my problem after i read your answer and JB Nizets' comments.
while this is some what off the topic of this question, what if I turn the tables around, that is, instead of having `A` call methods in `C`, define functions in `A` that `C` can call to do whatever it wants the plugin to do